# Select rows from table1 which don't have rows in table2

Tags: sql-server, select, sql-delete

I have 2 tables, OrderTable & OrderDetailTable.

I am trying to select rows from OrderTable that don't have any rows in OrderDetailTable so we can Delete them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you have an `id` relation between the 2 tables:

```
select * from OrderTable  
where orderdetails_id not in (select id from OrderDetailTable)
```

and to delete them

```
delete from OrderTable  
where orderdetails_id not in (select id from OrderDetailTable)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT o.*
FROM OrderTable o
LEFT JOIN OrderDetailTable od ON od.idOrderTable = o.id
WHERE od.id IS NULL;
```

od.id can be any field from OrderDetailTable that can't be null.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that OrderTable has a column id, and OrderDetailTable has a column orderTable_id

```
select * from OrderTable
WHERE id not in (
 select ot.id from OrderTable ot inner join OrderDetailTable odt on odt.orderTable_id = ot.id
)
```